# Can't see my running process in the netstat or lsof command?

Tags: c, bash, sockets, network-programming

I am trying my hands on socket programming. I've made the following file inetaddr.c and i am using Ubuntu 12.04.
The following code doesn't display my current running process on the console which it is supposed to when i execute it. I've tried the following two commands.

> system("netstat -pa --tcp 2>/dev/null | sed -n '1,/^Proto/p;/inetaddr/p'");

or even

> system("lsof -i tcp | sed -n '1p;/inetaddr/p'");

Is there anything wrong with what i've coded? How can i see the running process through netstat or lsof commands?

### inetaddr.c

```
/* inetaddr.c:
*
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
static void bail(const char *on_what) {
    fputs(on_what,stderr);
    fputc('\n',stderr);
    exit(1);
}
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
int z=0;
struct sockaddr_in adr_inet;/* AF_INET */
int len_inet; /* length */
int sck_inet; /* Socket */

 /* Create a Socket */
 sck_inet = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
printf("sck_inet = %d, PID = %u\n", sck_inet, getpid());
 if ( sck_inet < 0 )
    bail("socket()");

 /* Establish address */
 memset(&adr_inet,0,sizeof(adr_inet));

 adr_inet.sin_family = AF_INET;
 adr_inet.sin_port = htons(9000);

 adr_inet.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.95");

    if ( adr_inet.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE )
        bail("bad address.");
    len_inet = sizeof(adr_inet);
    printf("z value = %d before bind\n",z );
    z = bind(sck_inet, (struct sockaddr *)&adr_inet,len_inet);
    printf("z value = %d\n",z );
    if (z==-1)
        bail("bind()");
 /* Display our socket address */
    system("lsof -i tcp | sed -n '1p;/inetaddr/p'");
    //system("netstat -pa --tcp 2>/dev/null | sed -n '1,/^Proto/p;/bind/p'");
 return 0; 
}
```

### Makefile

```
all:    
    gcc -c -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall inetaddr.c
    gcc inetaddr.o -o inetaddr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a listen socket before the netstat. like this:

```
/* Display our socket address */
listen(sck_inet,50);  /* <--- Add this */
system("lsof -i tcp | sed -n '1p;/inetaddr/p'");
//system("netstat -pa --tcp 2>/dev/null | sed -n '1,/^Proto/p;/bind/p'");
return 0;
```

Comment: At least on linux the `netstat -ap` shows both listening and non-listening sockets. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: You are correct, although, after the listen I was able to list the program with both netstat and lsof. I'll edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: I believe that both lsof and netstat, shows only "open" or active sockets. For TCP sockets, that would be in LISTENING state, or any connection state, like ESTABLISHED, SYN_RECV, etc.

Comment: Thanks, solves my problem.
But can you give me a reference on what exactly are listening ports? Are these the same as open ports for communication?

Comment: When you are writting a server socket, you need set it to listening state, before you can "accept" connections. Whe you are on the client side, after you create a socket, you need to "connect" it to the server before sending and receiving data. This is of course, a very simple definition and applies to SOCK_STREAM (tcp) sockets. I  recommend some further reading like Richard Stevens books, "TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol. 1" or "Unix Network Programming, Volume 1" that can provide you with very good references and knowledge.